# How can I remove multiple characters in a list?

Tags: python, string, list

Having such list:

```
x = ['+5556', '-1539', '-99','+1500']
```

How can I remove + and - in nice way?

This works but I'm looking for more pythonic way.

```
x = ['+5556', '-1539', '-99', '+1500']
n = 0
for i in x:
    x[n] = i.replace('-','')
    n += 1
n = 0
for i in x:
    x[n] = i.replace('+','')
    n += 1
print x
```

## Edit

`+` and `-` are not always in leading position; they can be anywhere.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`str.strip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) or preferably [`str.lstrip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip):

```
In [1]: x = ['+5556', '-1539', '-99','+1500']
```

using `list comprehension`:

```
In [3]: [y.strip('+-') for y in x]
Out[3]: ['5556', '1539', '99', '1500']
```

using `map()`:

```
In [2]: map(lambda x:x.strip('+-'),x)
Out[2]: ['5556', '1539', '99', '1500']
```

**Edit:**

Use the `str.translate()` based [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14216120/846892) by @Duncan if you've `+` and `-` in between the numbers as well.

Comment: I would use the `translate` solution by @Duncan in the case where there are +- between the numbers.

Comment: @mgilson His solution wasn't posted when I edited my answer, so a +1 now.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out based on the timestamps.  I just thought since a newer (and better IMHO) answer existed, you should be made aware of it.

Answer (score 20):

Use `string.translate()`, or for Python 3.x `str.translate`:

Python 2.x:

```
>>> import string
>>> identity = string.maketrans("", "")
>>> "+5+3-2".translate(identity, "+-")
'532'
>>> x = ['+5556', '-1539', '-99', '+1500']
>>> x = [s.translate(identity, "+-") for s in x]
>>> x
['5556', '1539', '99', '1500']
```

Python 2.x unicode:

```
>>> u"+5+3-2".translate({ord(c): None for c in '+-'})
u'532'
```

Python 3.x version:

```
>>> no_plus_minus = str.maketrans("", "", "+-")
>>> "+5-3-2".translate(no_plus_minus)
'532'
>>> x = ['+5556', '-1539', '-99', '+1500']
>>> x = [s.translate(no_plus_minus) for s in x]
>>> x
['5556', '1539', '99', '1500']
```

Answer (score 12):

```
x = [i.replace('-', "").replace('+', '') for i in x]
```

Comment: very nice idea but if there are a lot more characters to remove, replace it would be to long

Answer (score 2):

`string.translate()` will only work on byte-string objects not unicode. I would use `re.sub`:

```
>>> import re
>>> x = ['+5556', '-1539', '-99','+1500', '45+34-12+']
>>> x = [re.sub('[+-]', '', item) for item in x]
>>> x
['5556', '1539', '99', '1500', '453412']
```

Comment: You can still use `value.translate()` on Python 2 when `value` is a unicode object but you need to pass in a different translation map. I updated my answer to include this case.

Answer (score 0):

These functions clean a list of strings of undesired characters.

```
lst = ['+5556', '-1539', '-99','+1500']
to_be_removed = "+-"

def remove(elem, to_be_removed):
    """ Remove characters from string"""
    return "".join([char for char in elem if char not in to_be_removed])

def clean_str(lst, to_be_removed):
   """Clean list of strings"""
   return [remove(elem, to_be_removed) for elem in lst]

clean_str(lst, to_be_removed)
# ['5556', '1539', '99', '1500']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
basestr ="HhEEeLLlOOFROlMTHEOTHERSIDEooEEEEEE"

def replacer (basestr, toBeRemove, newchar) :
    for i in toBeRemove :
        if i in basestr :
        basestr = basestr.replace(i, newchar)
    return basestr



newstring = replacer(basestr,['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'], "")

print(basestr)
print(newstring)
```

> Output :
>
> HhEEeLLlOOFROlMTHEOTHERSIDEooEEEEEE
>
> helloo

Comment: question is not about removing duplicates